# Disable office shortcut on win10 to open office

Tags: windows-10

When I press SHIFT, WINDOWS, ALTGR at the same time it opens the office app for me.( The image is what pops open ) I've tried to uninstall this but it won't help. Does any of you know how to disable this? Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKk4a.png